# on 4.4.2 kitkat "ImageView" not show

Tags: java, android, imageview, splash-screen

I have a "splash screen" showing until the webview loads in my app.

The splash is "ImageView". it is VISIBLE for "onPageStarted" and after "onPageFinished" the imageview is GONE and the Webview is VISIBLE.

It works well on my galaxy 3s 4.3 but on galaxy 5s 4.4.2 kitkat it loads the app without the image.

where is the problem!?

This my main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:id="@+id/rel_webpage_whole"
    android:background="#000000"
    >


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/splashload"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="#ffffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and MainActivity.java :

```
package com.com.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        String url="http://www.google.com";
        initWebView(webView,url);
         // TODO input your url

    }

    private final static Object methodInvoke(Object obj, String method, Class<?>[] parameterTypes, Object[] args) {
        try {
            Method m = obj.getClass().getMethod(method, new Class[] { boolean.class });
            m.invoke(obj, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    private void initWebView(WebView view, String url) {

        WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
        final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView); // i add this maybe this a problem
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginState", new Class[] { PluginState.class }, new Object[] { PluginState.ON });
        // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });

        view.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        view.clearHistory();
        view.clearFormData();
        view.clearCache(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);

        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);


            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                                      Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                dialog.setMessage("loading...");
                dialog.show();
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // i add this maybe this a problem


                dialog.dismiss();
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            }
        });

        view.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
        // webView.setDownloadListener(downloadListener);

    }
```

Comment: It may be that in version 4.4.2, your page loading is fast. So you might not be able to see splash screen. If you MUST show splash screen, you can show it for a fixed amount like, say, 3 seconds.

Comment: I would suggest you remove the splash screen altogether, as this goes against Android recommended guidelines. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEGWcMTxs3I&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8j2B95zGMb8muZvrIy-wcF#t=1403

Comment: @mystickMagic , It is not loading too fast. 
i have a dialog.show(); and this show until the webview finish.. the image only not show!

Comment: @kentarosu This is something I want to display the company logo. 
Do not understand why they are against it.

Comment: You could always just put the company logo anywhere else in the app, such as the ActionBar. You can also stylize the app with the company's colors. Splash screens do NOT belong on Android; they are normally useless and only slow down your users. Good examples are Instagram, Vine, and any Google app.

Comment: anyone know the problem?!!?